# SQL column percentage (with multiple group by)

Tags: sql, group-by, percentage

### Context

I have this view/exhibition, that lists records with sent date, client name, client position, type of refusal, total of IDClientPosition and total of IDRefusal. I use it to check how many claims sent on each date, were accepted, refused and why they were refused by each Client. (I have related tables to use for ClientPosition, Refusal and Client)

```
  DtSent    |  IDClient | IDClientPosition | TOTAL Position | IDRefusal | TOTAL Refusal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-10         1             1                 40           NULL           0
2020-01-10         1             1                 3              7            3
2020-01-10         1             2                 1            NULL           0
2020-02-10         2             2                 27             1           27
2020-02-10         2             2                 13             2           13
```

Query so far, that shows the above values:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.LBA.DtSent, dbo.Claims.IDClient, dbo.LBA.IDClientPosition, 
           COUNT(dbo.LBA.IDClientPosition) AS [TOTAL Position], dbo.LBA.IDRefusal, 
           COUNT(dbo.LBA.IDRefusal) AS [TOTAL Refusal]
FROM            dbo.LBA INNER JOIN
             dbo.ClientPositionLBA ON dbo.LBA.IDClientPosition = 
             dbo.ClientPositionLBA.IDClientPositLBA LEFT OUTER JOIN
             dbo.RefusalLBA ON dbo.LBA.IDRefusal = dbo.RefusalLBA.IDRefusal LEFT OUTER JOIN
             dbo.Claims LEFT OUTER JOIN
             dbo.Clients ON dbo.Claims.IDClient = dbo.Clients.IDClients ON 
             dbo.LBA.ClaimID = dbo.Claims.ClaimID
GROUP BY dbo.LBA.IDClientPosition, dbo.Claims.IDClient, dbo.LBA.IDRefusal, dbo.LBA.DtSent
```

### What I would like

I would like to add 2 columns, for percentages, based on the basis of the values of TOTAL Position and TOTAL Refusal.

With this, besides the total values that I already have (count), I could also know the percentage of how many claims were accepted, rejected and with what justification (IDRefusal), for that date, for each client. Summing up, it's like converting those total values to percentage.

Per month there should be around 100 records per client in a total of 20 clients, so it has to have in consideration the performance. I've tried scattered things I found online but with no avail.

Comment: (1) Show the results you want.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Learn to use table aliases:  queries are much easier to write and to read.

Comment: (1) You mean adding a column and just right a percentage to show I would like to see a percentage? (2) Sorry, didn't understand (3) I do use alias but as I was doing tests, forgot it. Should have thought it would help. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just divide by the total count:

```
COUNT(dbo.LBA.IDClientPosition) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
COUNT(dbo.LBA.IDRefusal) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.  The `* 1.0` produces a number with decimals so the calculation is more exact.

Comment: @Whoopcg . . . That appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm asking for a percentage. If Total Position column gives like 40 records total and another one returns 27, how can they both return 1.00000000 for percentage?